# Is there any way to find end tag in xml using vtd-xml

Tags: xml, tags, vtd-xml

I have use token to loop all element based on the token count
and see that in my xml structure, it has only token type = 5 and token type = 0 from this web

http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/userGuide/6.html

So is there a way to find ending tag in vtd-xml

Because, I have xml look like this.

```
<ZDA>
<userdata>
    <firstname>Eak</firstname>
    <lastname>Tan</lastname>
</userdata>
<list name="employee">
    <entry>
        <first_name>firstName</first_name>
        <title>title</title>
        <empid>1</empid>
        <second_name>secondName</second_name>
        <last_name>lastName</last_name>
        <date_of_birth>dateOfBirth</date_of_birth>
        <pin>pin</pin>
        <province>province</province>
        <start_date>startDate</start_date>
        <list name="address">
            <entry>
                <addressid>1</addressid>
                <empid>1</empid>
                <sequence>1</sequence>
                <detail>address11</detail>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <addressid>2</addressid>
                <empid>1</empid>
                <sequence>2</sequence>
                <detail>address12</detail>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <addressid>3</addressid>
                <empid>1</empid>
                <sequence>3</sequence>
                <detail>address13</detail>
            </entry>
        </list>
    </entry>    
</list>
```

I use ap.iterate() to loop through all the xml structure.

I want to use end tag to indicate that when it is reach --> `</entry>` add object to the current list. When it reach --> `</list>` add these list to the upper object if it have outer list.

And I want this procedure to be like a library so I use reflect to call method and object.

Right now, I only have a problem with how can the program know where to add accordingly.

So is any way to get end tag or parse XML to let it have end tags.

Best Regard, Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ending tag is not kept by the vtd parser, because it is the same as th starting tag. Any reason you  are looking for ending tags?

Comment: I just want to parse this xml into json by using pure java not using json external library (just connect string)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question, while I was unaware that you could find the close token as simply another element (as pointed out by the possibly well named @vtd-xml-author), I chose to go down the line of using the Navigation Object to parse each child.

First, I got the nav, then entered the first child. Then, I simply moved to the next siblings, registering the offset of the opening token, and then using the current offset with the previous offset to get the entire element. Once the next sibling move returned false, I quit back to the previous element, moved to the next sibling, and was able to calculate the position of the close for the final child element of the previous sibling (continuing to return to the parent when no more siblings, then using the length of the file when I got to the final element).

Comment: Interesting exercise, but most people prolly won't need it